# MMS messages received on my Samsung S7 start a new text thread that include me and I receive my own text as another text

Tags: mms

I have a Verizon phone Samsung S7.  I moved to T-MOBILE.  When I start a text thread and someone on the thread replies to the thread a d/or adds a pictureto it starts a new text thread and adds my mobile number to the thread.  Meaning if I reply to anyone's text I get the same message I just text texted back to me.  How can I stop this?  It's quite annoying